# When will Microsoft Windows Live Messenger stop working?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

All users of the MSN Messenger received an e-mail telling them that this service will be terminated. They still can use their accounts and see their contacts in Skype, but that's a different protocol and server.

When will it happen? The e-mail doesn't say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be in Q1 2013 (and March is also mentioned on some places).

**Sources**

1. [WebmasterServe.com](http://www.webmasterserve.com/forum-lobby/23778.htm)
2. [V3](http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/news/2222920/microsoft-retires-windows-live-messenger)
3. [thinkdigit](http://www.thinkdigit.com/Internet/Microsoft-to-retire-Windows-Live-Messenger-by_11294.html)

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate date I found was: [the first quarter of 2013](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2012/11/skypewlm.html)